# Show different marker for cluster and icon for single vector features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, clustering

I have a vector layer which is geoJSON file containing school points and their attributes,to visualize this i defined cluster and show circle which size is based on the number of features it contains. Whenever the zoom level reaches individual schools, i need to display symbol of school.

In style, i can define the size of cluster using the pointRadius property, and show icon using the externalGraphic property. i need to use both at once i.e use rendering as circle if cluster is more than one and render as icon in individual feautures.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used cluster icon in cluster and other icon in single feature.

```
var styles = new OpenLayers.Style({
    externalGraphic: "${symbol}"
},
{
    context:{
        symbol: function(feature){
            if (feature.cluster){
                return 'icon/Cluster_icon.png';
            }
            else{
                return 'icon/Single_icon.png';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it works if

```
var styles = new OpenLayers.Style({
externalGraphic: "${symbol}" }, {
context:{
    symbol: function(feature){
        if (feature.cluster.length != 1){
            return 'icon/Cluster_icon.png';
        }
        else{
            return 'icon/Single_icon.png';
        }
    }
}});
```

Comment: I have completed the project with the solution from neogeomat.I will try this one later in other projects. Thank you for the new way.

Comment: It will through error if the feature is not clustered. Correct answer is : `var styles = new OpenLayers.Style({
externalGraphic: "${symbol}" }, {
context:{
    symbol: function(feature){
        if (feature.cluster){
            return 'icon/Cluster_icon.png';
        }
        else{
            return 'icon/Single_icon.png';
        }
    }
}});`

Answer (score 0):

here is how i went about it in openlayers 5 (ol5) if this helps anyone in the future.

```
        let icon = new Style({
        image: new Icon(/** @type {module:ol/style/Icon~Options} */ ({
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            src: 'images/a.png'
        }))
    });

    let clusterIcon = new Style({
        image: new Icon(/** @type {module:ol/style/Icon~Options} */ ({
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            src: 'images/c.png'
        }))
    });

    let getIconStyle = function(feature) {
        if(feature.getProperties().features.length > 1) {
            return clusterIcon;
        }
        return icon;
    };

    let me = this;
    let vs = new VectorSource({
        loader: customeLoaderFunc
    });

    let clusterSource = new Cluster({
        distance: 15,
        threshold: 3,
        source: vs
    });

    let layer = new VectorLayer({
        source: clusterSource,
        visible: false,
        style:getIconStyle

    });
```